# Bootstrap Form - Save Form Data Into an array

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an array of football matches that I'll like users to enter their predictions. The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to get save this form into an array.

Here is the visual look of the form.
[Current form output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGejz.png)

Here's my react code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';
import { PredictTag, PotTitle, AmountInput } from '../../styles/styling';
import { Form, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { produce } from "immer";

const StakeForm = (props) => {
const { potter } = props;
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
  
]);

const pots = potter.pot.findPot.pot;

useEffect(() => {
  pots.slice(0, 4).map(() => {
    setInputList(currentInput => [{
      pot: {home_score: '', away_score: ''}
    }
    ]);
  })
},[]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row justify="space-around" align="middle">
        <Col span={12}><PotTitle>{potter.pot.findPot.pot_name}</PotTitle></Col>
        <Col span={12} className="mt-2">
            <PredictTag>Home</PredictTag>
            <PredictTag>Away</PredictTag>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Form>
        {pots.map(({_id, home_team, away_team, date, time}) => (
            <Row justify="space-around" align="middle" key={_id}>
                <Col span={12}>
                <h6>{home_team} vs {away_team}</h6>
                <p>{moment(date).format("MMM Do, YYYY")} | {moment(time).format('LT')}</p>
                </Col>
                <Col span={12}>
                {inputList.map((item, index) => (
                      <Container key={index}>
                        <Row>
                        <Col span={12}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="home" style={{ width: 100,  }}>
                          <Form.Control as="select" 
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            const home_score = e.target.value;
                            setInputList((currentInput) => 
                            produce(currentInput, (v) => {
                              v[index].pot.home_score = home_score;
                            })
                            )}}
                            >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                          </Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col span={12}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="away" style={{ width: 100, float: 'left' }}>
                          <Form.Control as="select"                           
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            const away_score = e.target.value;
                            setInputList((currentInput) => 
                            produce(currentInput, (v) => {
                              v[index].pot.away_score = away_score;
                            })
                            )}}
                          >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                          </Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>  
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                      </Container>
                  ))}    
                </Col>
            </Row>
        ))}
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(inputList, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Form>
  </Container>
  );
};


export default StakeForm;
```

Currently, all home_score and away_score fields only return a single output rather than creating an object for each of the matches. Please do help me on this.